# How can I have dynamic properties in go on the google app engine datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I want to do something like the [Expando Model](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#expando) that python supports on app engine.

> Sometimes you don't want to declare your properties ahead of time. A
>   special model subclass, Expando, changes the behavior of its entities
>   so that any attribute assigned (as long as it doesn't start with an
>   underscore) is saved to the Datastore.

How can I do this in Go?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Note beforehand:**

There are 2 APIs. The one with import path `appengine/datastore` uses channels as arguments. The other with import path `google.golang.org/appengine/datastore` uses slices. Adjust the example below to your case. See this question for details: [How to correctly import Golang appengine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32271148/how-to-correctly-import-golang-appengine)

---

The key to an entity with dynamic properties is the [`PropertyLoadSaver`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#PropertyLoadSaver) interface. By implementing this interface you can dynamically–at save time–construct the properties of the entity to be saved.

Also to not have to do this yourself the Go AppEngine platform provides a [`PropertyList`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#PropertyList) type which is basically a list (a slice) of properties [`Property`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#Property) and it also implements `PropertyLoadSaver`.

So the Expando model in Go is `PropertyList`. Just add the properties you want your entity to have, and save this `PropertyList` value.

Here is an example:

```
c := appengine.NewContext(r)

props := datastore.PropertyList{
    datastore.Property{Name: "time", Value: time.Now()},
    datastore.Property{Name: "email", Value: "me@myhost.com"},
}

k := datastore.NewIncompleteKey(c, "DynEntity", nil)
key, err := datastore.Put(c, k, &props)
c.Infof("%v %v", key, err)
```

This example saves an entity named `"DynEntity"` with 2 dynamic properties: `"time"` and `"email"`.

As the `PropertyList` type is a slice, you can also use the builtin [`append()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#append) function to add properties to it, so you could also initialize `props` like this:

```
var props datastore.PropertyList
props = append(props, datastore.Property{Name:"time", Value: time.Now()})
props = append(props, datastore.Property{Name:"email", Value: "me@myhost.com"})
```

### Turning a `map` into a dynamic entity

The `PropertyLoadSaver` interface is not complicated, we can implement it ourselves. In the following example I implement it on a custom type which is a simple `map`:

```
type DynEnt map[string]interface{}

func (d *DynEnt) Load(props []datastore.Property) error {
    // Note: you might want to clear current values from the map or create a new map
    for _, p := range props {
        (*d)[p.Name] = p.Value
    }
    return nil
}

func (d *DynEnt) Save() (props []datastore.Property, err error) {
    for k, v := range *d {
        props = append(props, datastore.Property{Name: k, Value: v})
    }
    return
}
```

Here's how the implementation would look like with the "old" interface that used channels instead of slices:

```
type DynEnt map[string]interface{}

func (d *DynEnt) Load(ch <-chan datastore.Property) error {
    // Note: you might want to clear current values from the map or create a new map
    for p := range ch { // Read until channel is closed
        (*d)[p.Name] = p.Value
    }
    return nil
}

func (d *DynEnt) Save(ch chan<- datastore.Property) error {
    defer close(ch) // Channel must be closed
    for k, v := range *d {
        ch <- datastore.Property{Name: k, Value: v}
    }
    return nil
}
```

Now we can use our `DynEnt` type just like any other maps in Go, and since it implements `PropertyLoadSaver`, it can be saved as an entity (and *any* entities can be loaded into it):

```
c := appengine.NewContext(r)

d := DynEnt{"email": "me@myhost.com", "time": time.Now()}

k := datastore.NewIncompleteKey(c, "DynEntity", nil)
key, err := datastore.Put(c, k, &d)
c.Infof("%v %v", key, err)
```

Comment: Why channels? In the docs the `PropertyLoadSaver` interface operates with slices?

Comment: @AlexanderTrakhimenok There are 2 APIs. The one with import path `appengine/datastore` uses channels as arguments. The other with import path `google.golang.org/appengine/datastore` uses slices. Adjust the example above to your case. Edited the answer.

Comment: Will this handle nested objects? i.e., can p.Value be another DynEnt?

Comment: @Gubbi The datastore entities are "flat" (no nesting), so there is no point trying to save a nested `DynEnt`.