# In Google App Engine for Go, how can a property have values of more than one type?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

The Google App Engine for Go [datastore docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/entities#Go_Properties_and_value_types) say, **"
A property can have values of more than one type"**. There is no example or further explanation. (Version: appengine 1.9.19.)

How can a property have more than one type if you must declare that property with a specific type in the backing struct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not necessarily have to declare a specific type for a property in a backing struct.

By implementing the [`PropertyLoadSaver`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#PropertyLoadSaver) interface, you can dynamically do whatever you want with the properties of an entity during loading or before saving. See [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29888449/1705598) which shows how to represent an entity as a general `map[string]interface{}` type in Go, so it can have dynamic properties.

#### Back to your question:

> A property can have values of more than one type.

This is true. But if you want to make this work, you will also have to utilize a custom loading/saving mechanism through the `PropertyLoadSaver` interface.

First define a backing `struct` where the property which will have multiple values of different types may be an `[]interface{}`:

```
type MyMy struct {
    Objects []interface{}
}
```

Next we have to implement `PropertyLoadSaver`. When loading, we will just append all values to the `Objects` slice that come with the name `"Objects"`.

When saving, we will loop over the elements of the `Objects` slice and send all its values with the same property name. This will ensure they will be saved under the same property, and we also have to specify the `Multiple` field to be `true` (multi-value property):

```
func (m *MyMy) Load(ch <-chan datastore.Property) error {
    for p := range ch { // Read until channel is closed
        if p.Name == "Objects" {
            m.Objects = append(m.Objects, p.Value)
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func (m *MyMy) Save(ch chan<- datastore.Property) error {
    defer close(ch)
    for _, v := range m.Objects {
        switch v2 := v.(type) {
        case int64: // Here v2 is of type int64
            ch <- datastore.Property{Name: "Objects", Value: v2, Multiple: true}
        case string:  // Here v2 is of type string
            ch <- datastore.Property{Name: "Objects", Value: v2, Multiple: true}
        case float64: // Here v2 is of type float64
            ch <- datastore.Property{Name: "Objects", Value: v2, Multiple: true}
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Note that setting a value of type `interface{}` as the `Property.Value` would result in an error, that is why I used a [Type switch](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_switches) so I will set concrete types. In my example I only supported 3 types (`int64`, `string` and `float64`) but you can just as easily add more types by adding new `case` branches.

#### And using it:

And finally using our custom `MyMy` type to save a new entity with property "Objects" which will have multiple values and of different types:

```
m := MyMy{[]interface{}{int64(1234), "strval", 32.2}}
key, err := datastore.Put(c, datastore.NewIncompleteKey(c, "MyMy", nil), &m)
```