# Creating structs programmatically at runtime - possible?

Tags: go, struct, reflection, types

Is it possible in Go to create a struct type programmatically (i.e. not in the compiled source code)?

We have a particular use case where a type will be created via user-defined metadata (so the schema/types are not known in advance)
and will vary for every customer. We would then need to auto-generate REST services for those and persist them in a NoSQL backend.
We would also need to define different dynamic validators per field (e.g. mandatory, regex, max/min size, max/min value, a reference to another type instance, etc.)

I was wondering if something similar is possible in the Go?

**Edit 1:**

For example

> From frontend in JSON

```
For customer 1:
{
"id":1,
"patientid":1,
"name":"test1",
"height":"160",
"weight":"70",
"temp":"98"
}

For customer 2:
{
"id":2,
"patientid":1,
"name":"test1",
"height":"160",
"weight":"70"
}

For customer 3

may be different new fields will add
```

> Backend

```
// For One customer need to have these fields 

type Vitalsigns struct {
    ID                int64  `datastore:"-"`
    PatientID         int64  `json:"patientid,omitempty"`
    Name              string `json:"name,omitempty"`
    Height            string `json:"height,omitempty"`
    Weight            string `json:"weight,omitempty"`
    Temp              string `json:"temp,omitempty"`
}



// Another need to have these fields

type Vitalsigns struct {
    ID                int64  `datastore:"-"`
    PatientID         int64  `json:"patientid,omitempty"`
    Name              string `json:"name,omitempty"`
    Height            string `json:"height,omitempty"`
    Weight            string `json:"weight,omitempty"`
}


//CreateVitalsignsHandler is to create vitals for a patient
func CreateVitalsignsHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {

    //Creating the Vitalsigns
    kinVitalsigns := &Vitalsigns{}
    ctx := appengine.NewContext(r)
    if err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(kinVitalsigns); err != nil {
        RespondErr(w, r, http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
        return
    }
    //Getting namespace
    namespace := ps.ByName("namespace")
    ctx, err := appengine.Namespace(ctx, namespace)
    if err != nil {
        log.Infof(ctx, "Namespace error from CreateVitalsignsHandler")
        RespondErr(w, r, http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
        return
    }
    //Geting the patientID
    pID, err := strconv.Atoi(ps.ByName("id"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Infof(ctx, "Srting to Int64 conversion error from CreateVitalsignsHandler")
        RespondErr(w, r, http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
        return
    }
    patientID := int64(pID)
    kinVitalsigns.PatientID = patientID

    //Generating the key
    vitalsignsKey := datastore.NewIncompleteKey(ctx, "Vitalsigns", nil)

    //Inserting the data to the datastore
    vk, err := datastore.Put(ctx, vitalsignsKey, kinVitalsigns)
    if err != nil {
        log.Infof(ctx, "Entity creation was failed from CreateVitalsignsHandler")
        RespondErr(w, r, http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
        return
    }
    kinVitalsigns.ID = vk.IntID()
    message := "Vitalsigns created successfully!! "
    Respond(w, r, http.StatusOK, SuccessResponse{kinVitalsigns.ID, 0, "", message})
    return
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Edit:** Your edit reveals you want to handle dynamic objects to put / retrieve from Google Datastore. For this it is completely unnecessary to create struct types at runtime, you may just use a dynamic map presented in this answer: [How can I have dynamic properties in go on the google app engine datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29885431/how-can-i-have-dynamic-properties-in-go-on-the-google-app-engine-datastore/29888449#29888449).

Original answer follows.

---

Note that if the types are known at compile time, best / most efficient is to create the types and compile them, so everything will be "static". You may create the types manually, or you may use `go generate` to automate the process.

Also note that you may not necessarily need struct types to model dynamic objects, many times maps may be sufficient.

If types are not known at compile time, and struct types are a must, read on.

**Yes, it's possible to create "dynamic" struct types at runtime** using Go's reflection, specifically with the [`reflect.StructOf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructOf) function.

Let's see a simple example, creating a struct type at runtime that has a `Name string` and an `Age int` field:

```
t := reflect.StructOf([]reflect.StructField{
    {
        Name: "Name",
        Type: reflect.TypeOf(""), // string
    },
    {
        Name: "Age",
        Type: reflect.TypeOf(0), // int
    },
})

fmt.Println(t)

v := reflect.New(t)
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", v)
v.Elem().FieldByName("Name").Set(reflect.ValueOf("Bob"))
v.Elem().FieldByName("Age").Set(reflect.ValueOf(12))

fmt.Printf("%+v\n", v)
```

This outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/4s2YPLKLUhd)):

```
struct { Name string; Age int }
&{Name: Age:0}
&{Name:Bob Age:12}
```

If you want to define validation rules, you may use a 3rd party lib for that, for example [`github.com/go-validator/validator`](https://github.com/go-validator/validator). This package uses [struct tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go/30889373#30889373) to specify validation rules, struct tags which you may also specify using reflection.

For example, if you want to specify that the `Name` must be at least 3 characters and 40 at most, and it may only contain letters of the English alphabet, and valid range for `Age` is `6..100` (both inclusive), this is how it would look like:

```
t := reflect.StructOf([]reflect.StructField{
    {
        Name: "Name",
        Type: reflect.TypeOf(""), // string
        Tag:  reflect.StructTag(`validate:"min=3,max=40,regexp=^[a-zA-Z]*$"`),
    },
    {
        Name: "Age",
        Type: reflect.TypeOf(0), // int
        Tag:  reflect.StructTag(`validate:"min=6,max=100"`),
    },
})
```

Printing this type would output (wrapped by me) (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/W3h7fyqnKQb)):

```
struct { Name string "validate:\"min=3,max=40,regexp=^[a-zA-Z]*$\"";
    Age int "validate:\"min=6,max=100\"" }
```

Once you create an instance of this struct, you can validate it using the [`validator.Validate()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/validator.v2#Validate) function, e.g.:

```
v := reflect.New(t)
v.Elem().FieldByName("Name").Set(reflect.ValueOf("Bob"))
v.Elem().FieldByName("Age").Set(reflect.ValueOf(12))

if errs := validator.Validate(v.Elem().Interface()); errs != nil {
    // values not valid, deal with errors here
}
```

Comment: I have updated my answer little confusing use in the above code
I will get dynamic JSON from the frontend, how I can convert to a struct to insert data to datastore.

Comment: While this is a great solution to the posted question, I would very strongly discourage using it. This seems like a nightmare to manage, slow to run, and in the end very likely to be pointless. Compile-time structs or maps are almost certainly the better solution.

Comment: @Adrian any suggestion

Comment: @Adrian Yes, this is exactly what I suggest in my first paragraph, the "rest" is to answer the question.

Comment: Yep, just a second vote for "really, don't do this, even though it's possible"!

Comment: Sometimes you need to do it though. I for example have a use-case where the data structure is created at runtime from a json schema and I found that using a struct created at runtime (using github.com/modern-go/reflect2 to create new instances) is heaps more performant than using a map.