# Unable to insert dynamic properties in go on the google app engine datastore

Tags: dictionary, google-app-engine, go, datastore

I am trying to working from this post 
[How can I have dynamic properties in go on the google app engine datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29885431/how-can-i-have-dynamic-properties-in-go-on-the-google-app-engine-datastore)

Unable to insert the data to the datastore, It is only creating ID

```
import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"

    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
    "google.golang.org/appengine"
    "google.golang.org/appengine/datastore"
)

type DynEnt map[string]interface{}

func (d *DynEnt) Load(props []datastore.Property) error {
    // Note: you might want to clear current values from the map or create a new map
    for _, p := range props {
        (*d)[p.Name] = p.Value
    }
    return nil
}

func (d *DynEnt) Save() (props []datastore.Property, err error) {
    for k, v := range *d {
        props = append(props, datastore.Property{Name: k, Value: v})
    }
    return nil, nil
}

//GetAccountHandler is to
func GetAccountHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {

    c := appengine.NewContext(r)

    d := DynEnt{"email": "me@myhost.com", "time": time.Now()}
    log.Println("d=>", d)
    log.Println("&d=>", &d)
    k := datastore.NewIncompleteKey(c, "DynEntity", nil)
    key, err := datastore.Put(c, k, &d)
    log.Fatalf("%v %v", key, err)

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a typo in [my original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29885431/how-can-i-have-dynamic-properties-in-go-on-the-google-app-engine-datastore/29888449#29888449), the return value at the end of `Save()` was a copy/paste mistake (from the channel version). The correct version is:

```
func (d *DynEnt) Save() (props []datastore.Property, err error) {
    for k, v := range *d {
        props = append(props, datastore.Property{Name: k, Value: v})
    }
    return
}
```

Note that there are no values specified after `return` because named result parameters are used. Specifying `nil, nil` would not return the slice built inside `Save()`.

Also you call `log.Fatalf()` at the end of your handler, that terminates your app. Try `log.Printf()` instead.